# PHPExcel: Change Worksheet order

Tags: php, phpexcel

I create some worksheets in PHPExcel:

```
$objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet("A");
$objPHPExcel->addSheet($objWorkSheet);
$objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet("B");
$objPHPExcel->addSheet($objWorkSheet);
$objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet("C");
$objPHPExcel->addSheet($objWorkSheet);
```

Is it possible to change the order of the worksheets afterwards?

Comment: as per on PHPExcel documentation, they don't have any method to do this.

Comment: should be doable by manipulating the object

Answer (score 1):

I created this function that moves a tab to the last position of the spreadsheet.
Parameter: Name of the tab to be moved.
If the tab does not exist, it does nothing.
It was added to PHPExcel.php after the removeSheetByIndex function (line 255).
I hope it helps.

```
/**
* Move sheet by name to the end
*
* @param string $pName Sheet name
* if sheet $pName not found, do nothing!!
*/
public function moveSheetByName($pName = '')
{
    if (($worksheet = $this->getSheetByName($pName)) instanceof PHPExcel_Worksheet) {
        $pIndex = $this->getIndex($this->getSheetByName($pName));
        $pSheettoMove = array_splice($this->_workSheetCollection, $pIndex, 1);
        $this->addSheet($pSheettoMove[0]);              
    }
}
```